# How can you change the Visual Studio IDE profile?

Tags: visual-studio

Can the Visual Studio IDE profile be changed without clearing all VS settings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tools -> Import and Export Settings.. -> [X] Import Selected ... -> Save Current -> Choose options you wish to change

Comment: Those options don't appear in my VS2010