# Microsoft Visual Studio Environment

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I installed Microsoft Visual Studio I told it to optimize for C#.  That is, when asked, I indicated that I would be programming in C# most of the time.  Is there a way to change the environment, so that it is optimized for working with C++ without uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio?  Could I do another install of Visual Studio on top of the current install without uninstalling it first?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that VS is referring mainly to the keybindings and possibly initial window layout/default template options with this choice. It's not a performance thing for the application itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this post

[How can you change the Visual Studio IDE profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112926/how-can-you-change-the-visual-studio-ide-profile)

Comment: If you chose Reset all settings you should be re-prompted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line option /resetsettings to reset visual studio settings

devenv.exe /ResetSettings

This will enable Visual Studio to bring up the environment dialog again.